# How to pass multiple json objects of array to post request in jmeter using groovy script

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

POST API is triggering fine and taking only first json object from array and rest of the json objects are not passing. I need to trigger API with multiple json payloads sequentially using JMeter and Groovy.

json payload : Below is the sample json payload

```
 [
{
"person": "abc",
"Id": "123"},
{
"person": "adfg",
"Id": "12883"},
{
"person": "adf",
"Id": "125"}
]
```

Groovy code : Reading data from json file which includes multiple json objects and send it to post request in jmeter.

try
{

```
JsonSlurper jsonSlurper=new JsonSlurper();

def jsonPayload = jsonSlurper.parse(new File('PAYLOAD.json'))

String inputData = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(jsonPayload)
JsonElement root = new JsonParser().parse(inputData);
JsonArray  jsonArray = root.getAsJsonArray();
log.info("jsonArray:"+jsonArray);

if(jsonArray != null && !jsonArray.isEmpty())  
{
jsonArray.each{paylodData -> 
println paylodData
log.info("post data:"+paylodData);
vars.putObject("payloads", paylodData.toString())
log.info('Generated body: ' + vars.getObject('payloads'))
}

}
}catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {

log.info("Error: Please Check the file path");
        
}

JMeter Test :  Triggering same API with multiple payloads

using below variable in post request body 

${payloads}


NOTE : API is triggering fine and taking only first json object and rest of the json objects are not passing. I need to trigger API with multiple json payloads sequentially.
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?

You have a [foreach loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop) which iterates the JSON Array and writes the inner object value into a  `payloads` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

The point is that each iteration of the foreach loop **overwrites** the previous value in the variable so you will always get the **last** value.

You either need to replace `jsonArray.each` with [`jsonArray.eachWithIndex`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#_iterating_on_a_list) and store each array member into a separate variable like:

```
payload_0 = first array member
payload_1 = second array member 
etc.
```

or transform the response into another format, but here I cannot suggest anything because I don't know what is the expected one.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Im using this jmeter function in post request body  ${__V(payloads_${__counter(TRUE,)})} and from groovy script side..  i have written the logic like below jsonArray.eachWithIndex{it,index->
   
println "value " + it + " at index " +index
 
log.info("sapstore post data:"+it);
vars.putObject("payloads", it.toString())
log.info('Generated body: ' + vars.getObject('payloads'))
}

Comment: but still its not taking the json payload in to post request body and in logs its printing like this  ---   (The PostBody is :: payloads_1  )

Comment: I'm not telepathic enough to guess why your code doesn't work unless I see it, here is the working one: `new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(new File('PAYLOAD.json')).eachWithIndex { entry, index -> vars.put('payload_' + (index + 1), new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(entry).toPrettyString())}` . You may also find [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-templates) article useful.

Comment: From groovy scripting side its working fine for me. But the problem with the post body  of POST request api call in JMeter. Its taking only the first object and not the rest sequentially.  I have tried with both the functions  ${payloads} or  ${__V(payloads_${__counter(TRUE,)})} .  Please suggest me what i have to pass in the post body.

Comment: I have tried using this function as well ${__BeanShell(bsh.shared.payloads.get(${counter})),)}  in post request body and this function also not working

Comment: You do have problem with "groovy scripting side" and if you even gave a try to read and understand my answer you would see it as well. If you don't trust my words double check JMeter Variables values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scripts) and you will see that all 3 variables have the same (last) value. Demo of my approach working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU2td.gif.

Comment: your approach is working fine. Im performing this testing not from JMeter tool.. I have written the test steps from JMETER CSV test case like below. (JMETERTESTCASE.CSV file)
1,HEAD,SCRIPT,GROOVY,,,,,
1,READ_PAYLOADS,,,,,,,,,,,
2,HEAD,TRIGGER,APICALL,,
2,POST_PAYLOAD,,${payloads},,,,,

TEST STEP NO.2  is to trigger API call and in second line we are passing multiple dynamic json payloads
POST_PAYLOAD.tmpl  -  ${__V(payloads_${__counter(,)},)}

Comment: Im passing this  ${__V(payloads_${__counter(,)},)} in post request body. but from JMETER its taking only one payload and not taking the rest of the payloads. Can you please assist me  where else im doing the mistake

Comment: I can see that you had setup loop count as 3 in JMETER tool. so similar to that can we do setup in groovy script.

Comment: If you're "performing this testing not from JMeter tool" then contact "your" tool support as I have no idea what "tool" you're using.

Comment: Im using JMeter only but not testing it from JMETER UI dashboard. Im testing With help of JMeter tool in jenkins and executing my jmeter test cases (eg : ReadPayloadsJmeterTest.csv file)

Comment: Is there any way to add loop count from groovy script to trigger post api call multiple times based on input payloads.

Comment: this is my groovy script                                                              jsonArray.eachWithIndex{it,index->
   
println "value " + it + " at index " +index
 
log.info("sapstore post data:"+it);
props.put('payloads_' + (index + 1), it.toString())
data = props.get('payloads_' + (index + 1));
log.info("data is "+data);

}
}

Comment: and below  line im passing it from post request                                                                        ${__groovy(props.get("payloads_" + vars.getIteration()),)}